# Can't perform methods of objects stored in Array[Any]

Tags: ios, swift, casting, any, anyobject

I want to store objects of different types in an array.
The program below is only a minimum demo. In the anyArray:[Any] an instance of Object1 is stored. The print statement prints out the expected object type. In the following line the test of the stored object's type returns true. This means, during run time the correct object type is known and every thing seems to be fine.

```
    class Object1 {
        var name = "Object1"
    }

    var anyArray:[Any] = [Object1()]
    print("\(type(of: anyArray[0]))")
    let testResult = anyArray[0] is Object1
    print("Test result:\(testResult)")
    //print("Name:\((anyArray[0]).name)")

Console output:
   Object1
   Test result:true
```

However, if I try to print out the name property of the object, I get an error message from the editor:

```
Value of type 'Any' has no member 'name'
```

Well, at compile time the object's type is unknown. That's why the compiler complains. How can I tell the compiler that it is OK to access the properties of the stored object?

Comment: This is Swift, use a protocol which all different objects conform to. `Any` is the worst type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference comes from the difference from *Type Checking* in:

- *runtime*, or
- *compile time*

The `is` operator checks at runtime whether the expression can be cast to the specified type. `type(of:)` checks, at runtime, the exact type, without consideration for subclasses.

`anyArray[0].name` doesn't compile since the Type `Any` doesn't have a `name` property.

If you're sure `anyArray[0]` is an `Object1`, you could use the downcast operator `as!`:

```
print("\((anyArray[0] as! Object1).name)")
```

To check at runtime if an element from `anyArray` could be an `Object1` use optional binding, using the conditional casting operator `as?`:

- if let:

  ```
  if let object = anyArray[0] as? Object1 {
      print(object.name)
  }
  ```
- Or use the `guard` statement, if you want to use that object in the rest of the scope:

  ```
  guard let object = anyArray[0] as? Object1 else {
      fatalError("The first element is not an Object1")
  }
  print(object.name)
  ```

---

If all objects in your array have a `name` property, and you don't want to go through all the hoops of optional binding repeatedly, then use a protocol. Your code will look like this:

```
protocol Named {
    var name: String {get set}
}

class Object1: Named {
    var name = "Object1"
}

var anyArray:[Named] = [Object1()]
print("\(type(of: anyArray[0]))")
let testResult = anyArray[0] is Object1
print("Test result:\(testResult)")
print("Name:\(anyArray[0].name)")
```

Notice that `anyArray` is now an array of `Named` objects, and that `Object1` conforms to the `Named` protocol.

To learn more about protocols, have a look [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html).

Comment: I want to store objects with different types in anyArray. However, all this types have in common that they have a property name. I want to read out the object and modify the property name. There is no need for me to know which kind of type I have got from the array. But, at compile time the compiler doesn't know about the fact that all objects stored in array have a property name. So the compiler has to complain. I am looking for a way to tell the compiler that the type of the objects stored in anyArray can't be guaranteed. May be, this is impossible with Swift.

Comment: @HeinzM. I see you'll have to use a protocol. I'll update my answer

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: Now I want to test two objects for equality anyArray[0] == someOtherObject. I get the error message Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'CellProtocol' operands

Comment: @HeinzM. Maybe that would be better in a new question. `==` can only be used between equatable objects. Your objects will have to conform to the *Equatable* protocol.

Answer (score 2):

You object is still of type `Any`. You just checked if it can be of type `Object1`, but you did not cast it. If you want the object as `Object1`, you need to **cast** it.

Also if multiple classes can have name, you need to use `Protocol` like @vadian has mentioned in his comment and cast it to that protocol.

```
protocol NameProtocol {
    var name: String {get set}
}

class Object1: NameProtocol {
    var name = "Object1"
}

if let testResult = anyArray[0] as? NameProtocol {
     print(testResult.name)
}
```

**Edit:** *"I want to store objects of different types in an array".* The solution that you have marked as correct will not work if all the objects that you have do not conform to the protocol.